# Does "Glass Half Full" affect PvP in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

All damage is equalized among players in PvP. So, perks like "Upgrade Damage" are meaningless. Does this also apply to perks like "Glass Half Full"?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think it does work in PvP. While damage is equalized, some guns do more damage than others, so this would be a way to increase damage. If I remember, I'll try to test it next time I play.

Comment: Thank you. I just bought the auto rifle "For the People" and wondered this while looking through its upgrade tree. So, it's going to be a while until I can test. Let me know what you find! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to test this today. I used the Vanquisher VIII that you buy from the New Monarchy vendor.

Normally it does 22 damage when you hit the opponent's body. The bottom half of the clip did 23 damage, so Glass Half Full does work in PvP.

I wasn't able to tell how much headshots increase in damage, but I would assume that it is by a similar amount.

Comment: Now that 1.1.1 patch is out (with auto rifles nerf), numbers can be a little bit different. It does not affect the fact that perk works though.